# What Equipment and Software do I need for dynamic smart card access control

Tags: smartcard, access-control

I am doing a research on creating an access control system that utilizes a smart card reader, a magnetic door lock and an existing information system developed on the .NET Framework that should avail data that the access control system then uses to determine if access should be granted or not. I have been searching for some kind of programmable access control system (smart card reader and magnetic door lock) that can also be connected to an information system over a network, but my search is yielding no helpful results. Could someone help me with some information on what equipment and software I would need to pull this off?

Answer (score 1):

The important trigger word is *physical access control* as opposed to the access of software services (for which the tag is intended). Most card reader manufacturers offer something in that direction, as e. g. [HID](http://www.hidglobal.com/solutions/dynamic-access-control).

Also physical access control is often combined with attendance acquisition [Siemens Siport](http://www.buildingtechnologies.siemens.com/bt/global/en/security-solution/access-control-systems/Pages/access-control-systems.aspx), an access zone management, time restrictions etc.

That access privileges or entry/exit time stamps can be queried over the network goes without saying, of course modification of privileges has to be carefully restricted.